Calling Dialogflow in Salesforce Community
I have a requirement to call google dialog in the Salesforce community. Using innerHTML tag I inserted the component but I am not able to see the bubble icon in the community. I need some guidance on how I can show the dialog flow bubble in the community.
Html Code:
<template>
<div data-id="gdialog"></div>
</template>

Javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import dialogflow from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/googleDialogJS';
export default class Googledialogflow extends LightningElement {
        renderedCallback() {                    
        const gdialogElement = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="gdialog"]');
       
        gdialogElement.innerHTML = '<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script><df-messenger intent="WELCOME" chat-title="NewAgent" agent-id="<<<Agent ID Key>>>" language-code="en"></df-messenger>';           
        
}

